# Tailwind sidebar component to React

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm leveraging tailwind as a sidebar for a project. I'm re-using a HTML component, and I cannot get the sidebar to work appropriately in react.

This is the component,

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'

import NotificationDropdown from "./functions/NotificationDropdown.js";
import UserDropdown from "./functions/UserDropdown.js";

export default function Sidebar() {
const [isOn, setIsOn] = useState(false)

return (
<>
    <div className="md:hidden">
    <div className="fixed inset-0 flex z-40">

      <div className="fixed inset-0">
        <div className="absolute inset-0 bg-gray-600 opacity-75"></div>
      </div>

      <div className="relative flex-1 flex flex-col max-w-xs w-full bg-gray-800">
        <div className="absolute top-0 right-0 -mr-14 p-1">
          <button className="flex items-center justify-center h-12 w-12 rounded-full focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-600" 
          
          aria-label="Close sidebar">
            <svg className="h-6 w-6 text-white" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
              <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
            </svg>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-1 h-0 pt-5 pb-4 overflow-y-auto">
          <div className="flex-shrink-0 flex items-center px-4">
            
            <img className="h-8 w-auto" src="/static/workflow-logo-on-dark.svg" alt="Workflow" />
          </div>
          <nav className="mt-5 px-2">
          <Link href="/PropertyWatch/redevelopment"><a className="group flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-base leading-6 font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-700 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
              <svg className="mr-4 h-6 w-6 text-gray-300 group-hover:text-gray-300 group-focus:text-gray-300 transition ease-in-out duration-150" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="M3 12l2-2m0 0l7-7 7 7M5 10v10a1 1 0 001 1h3m10-11l2 2m-2-2v10a1 1 0 01-1 1h-3m-6 0a1 1 0 001-1v-4a1 1 0 011-1h2a1 1 0 011 1v4a1 1 0 001 1m-6 0h6"/>
              </svg>
              Dashboard
            </a></Link>
            
            <Link href="/PropertyWatch/bargains"><a className="mt-1 group flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-base leading-6 font-medium rounded-md text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
              <svg className="mr-4 h-6 w-6 text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-300 group-focus:text-gray-300 transition ease-in-out duration-150" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="M12 4.354a4 4 0 110 5.292M15 21H3v-1a6 6 0 0112 0v1zm0 0h6v-1a6 6 0 00-9-5.197M13 7a4 4 0 11-8 0 4 4 0 018 0z"/>
              </svg>
              Bargain Hunting
            </a></Link>
            
            <a href="#" className="mt-1 group flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-base leading-6 font-medium rounded-md text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
              <svg className="mr-4 h-6 w-6 text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-300 group-focus:text-gray-300 transition ease-in-out duration-150" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="M3 7v10a2 2 0 002 2h14a2 2 0 002-2V9a2 2 0 00-2-2h-6l-2-2H5a2 2 0 00-2 2z"/>
              </svg>
              Projects
            </a>
            <a href="#" className="mt-1 group flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-base leading-6 font-medium rounded-md text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
              <svg className="mr-4 h-6 w-6 text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-300 group-focus:text-gray-300 transition ease-in-out duration-150" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="M8 7V3m8 4V3m-9 8h10M5 21h14a2 2 0 002-2V7a2 2 0 00-2-2H5a2 2 0 00-2 2v12a2 2 0 002 2z"/>
              </svg>
              Calendar
            </a>
            <a href="#" className="mt-1 group flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-base leading-6 font-medium rounded-md text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
              <svg className="mr-4 h-6 w-6 text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-300 group-focus:text-gray-300 transition ease-in-out duration-150" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="M20 13V6a2 2 0 00-2-2H6a2 2 0 00-2 2v7m16 0v5a2 2 0 01-2 2H6a2 2 0 01-2-2v-5m16 0h-2.586a1 1 0 00-.707.293l-2.414 2.414a1 1 0 01-.707.293h-3.172a1 1 0 01-.707-.293l-2.414-2.414A1 1 0 006.586 13H4"/>
              </svg>
              Documents
            </a>
            <a href="#" className="mt-1 group flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-base leading-6 font-medium rounded-md text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
              <svg className="mr-4 h-6 w-6 text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-300 group-focus:text-gray-300 transition ease-in-out duration-150" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="M9 19v-6a2 2 0 00-2-2H5a2 2 0 00-2 2v6a2 2 0 002 2h2a2 2 0 002-2zm0 0V9a2 2 0 012-2h2a2 2 0 012 2v10m-6 0a2 2 0 002 2h2a2 2 0 002-2m0 0V5a2 2 0 012-2h2a2 2 0 012 2v14a2 2 0 01-2 2h-2a2 2 0 01-2-2z"/>
              </svg>
              Reports
            </a>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-shrink-0 flex bg-gray-700 p-4">
        <Link href="/account/user">
        <a className="flex-shrink-0 group block">
            <div className="flex items-center">
              <div>
                <img className="inline-block h-10 w-10 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472099645785-5658abf4ff4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80" alt="" />
              </div>
              <div className="ml-3">
                <p className="text-base leading-6 font-medium text-white">
                  Tom Cook
                </p>
                <p className="text-sm leading-5 font-medium text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-300 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
                  View profile
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a></Link>
         
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="flex-shrink-0 w-14">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div className="hidden md:flex md:flex-shrink-0">
    <div className="flex flex-col w-64 bg-gray-800">
      <div className="h-0 flex-1 flex flex-col pt-5 pb-4 overflow-y-auto">
        <div className="flex items-center flex-shrink-0 px-4">
          <img className="h-8 w-auto" src="/static/workflow-logo-on-dark.svg" alt="Workflow" />
        </div>
        <nav className="mt-5 flex-1 px-2 bg-gray-800">

        <Link href="/PropertyWatch/redevelopment"><a href="#" className="group flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-sm leading-5 font-medium text-white rounded-md bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-700 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
            <svg className="mr-3 h-6 w-6 text-gray-300 group-hover:text-gray-300 group-focus:text-gray-300 transition ease-in-out duration-150" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
              <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="M3 12l2-2m0 0l7-7 7 7M5 10v10a1 1 0 001 1h3m10-11l2 2m-2-2v10a1 1 0 01-1 1h-3m-6 0a1 1 0 001-1v-4a1 1 0 011-1h2a1 1 0 011 1v4a1 1 0 001 1m-6 0h6"/>
            </svg>
            Dashboard
          </a></Link>
          

          <Link href="/PropertyWatch/bargains"><a href="#" className="mt-1 group flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-sm leading-5 font-medium text-gray-300 rounded-md hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
            <svg className="mr-3 h-6 w-6 text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-300 group-focus:text-gray-300 transition ease-in-out duration-150" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
              <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="M12 4.354a4 4 0 110 5.292M15 21H3v-1a6 6 0 0112 0v1zm0 0h6v-1a6 6 0 00-9-5.197M13 7a4 4 0 11-8 0 4 4 0 018 0z"/>
            </svg>
            Bargain Hunting
          </a></Link>

         
          <a href="#" className="mt-1 group flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-sm leading-5 font-medium text-gray-300 rounded-md hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
            <svg className="mr-3 h-6 w-6 text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-300 group-focus:text-gray-300 transition ease-in-out duration-150" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
              <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="M3 7v10a2 2 0 002 2h14a2 2 0 002-2V9a2 2 0 00-2-2h-6l-2-2H5a2 2 0 00-2 2z"/>
            </svg>
            Projects
          </a>
          <a href="#" className="mt-1 group flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-sm leading-5 font-medium text-gray-300 rounded-md hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
            <svg className="mr-3 h-6 w-6 text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-300 group-focus:text-gray-300 transition ease-in-out duration-150" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
              <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="M8 7V3m8 4V3m-9 8h10M5 21h14a2 2 0 002-2V7a2 2 0 00-2-2H5a2 2 0 00-2 2v12a2 2 0 002 2z"/>
            </svg>
            Calendar
          </a>
          <a href="#" className="mt-1 group flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-sm leading-5 font-medium text-gray-300 rounded-md hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
            <svg className="mr-3 h-6 w-6 text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-300 group-focus:text-gray-300 transition ease-in-out duration-150" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
              <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="M20 13V6a2 2 0 00-2-2H6a2 2 0 00-2 2v7m16 0v5a2 2 0 01-2 2H6a2 2 0 01-2-2v-5m16 0h-2.586a1 1 0 00-.707.293l-2.414 2.414a1 1 0 01-.707.293h-3.172a1 1 0 01-.707-.293l-2.414-2.414A1 1 0 006.586 13H4"/>
            </svg>
            Documents
          </a>
          <a href="#" className="mt-1 group flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-sm leading-5 font-medium text-gray-300 rounded-md hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
            <svg className="mr-3 h-6 w-6 text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-300 group-focus:text-gray-300 transition ease-in-out duration-150" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
              <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="M9 19v-6a2 2 0 00-2-2H5a2 2 0 00-2 2v6a2 2 0 002 2h2a2 2 0 002-2zm0 0V9a2 2 0 012-2h2a2 2 0 012 2v10m-6 0a2 2 0 002 2h2a2 2 0 002-2m0 0V5a2 2 0 012-2h2a2 2 0 012 2v14a2 2 0 01-2 2h-2a2 2 0 01-2-2z"/>
            </svg>
            Reports
          </a>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div className="flex-shrink-0 flex bg-gray-700 p-4">
      <Link href="/account/user">
      <a className="flex-shrink-0 w-full group block">
          <div className="flex items-center">
            <div>
              <img className="inline-block h-9 w-9 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472099645785-5658abf4ff4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div className="ml-3">
              <p className="text-sm leading-5 font-medium text-white">
                Tom Cook
              </p>
              <p className="text-xs leading-4 font-medium text-gray-300 group-hover:text-gray-200 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
                View profile
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a></Link>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </>
  );
}
```

Now to make this work in React I know I need to conditionally include the necessary classes on each element by checking a prop or piece of state.

That said, When I've tried to implement this, it's failed for some reason.

Would love some guidance on this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To conditionally include or exclude classes based on a variable/state object, you should use https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames. It is the recommended ([even by the react team](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html#how-do-i-add-css-classes-to-components)) way of doing this.